# Sistema de login com permissão

Tags: php, mysql, login, permissões

Tenho um sistema de login que, caso o usuário seja um administrador, será redirecionado para uma página e caso seja comum, para outra.

**A tabela:**

Para isso, tenho uma coluna na tabela que armazena usuários chamada ativo, onde 0 é usuário comum e 1 é administrador.

**O login:**

```
    <!--A parte do formulário-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="
    margin-top: 14px;">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Login</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="background: rgba(32, 40, 76, 0.59);">
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($erro)) 
                            if(count($erro) > 0){ ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <?php foreach($erro as $msg) echo "$msg <br>"; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php 
                            }
                            ?>
                        <form method="post" action="" role="form">
                            <fieldset style="background: #9498a9;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" name="identifiant">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" required placeholder="Senha" name="senha" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Lembrar-me
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" name="login" value="true" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="background: #232b4f; border-color: #e2e2e2;">Login</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!--A lógica-->
    <?php
        session_start();

        //Login de Usários
    if($_POST){

    include('class/conexao.php');

    $erro = array();

    // Captação de dados
    $senha = mysqli->escape_string($_POST[senha]);
    $_SESSION['identifiant'] = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['identifiant']);

    // Validação de dados
    if(strlen($identifiant) < 7 || strlen($identifiant) > 7){
        $erro[] = "Preencha sua <strong>identifiant</strong> corretamente.";
    }else if(strlen($senha) < 5 || strlen($senha) > 16){
        $erro[] = "Preencha sua <strong>senha</strong> corretamente.";
    }else{
    //Até aqui, se não tiver nenhum erro nessa lista de erros aí, prossegue.

        $sql = "SELECT senha as senha, identifiant as valor
        FROM usuarios
        WHERE identifiant = '$_SESSION[identifiant]'";
        $que = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
        $dado = $que->fetch_assoc();

        if($que->num_rows == 0){
            $erro[] = "Usuário ou senha inválidos.";

        }else{

            if($_SESSION['identifiant'] == 0){
                echo "<script>location.href='http://127.0.0.1/formacao/principal.php';</script>";
                exit();
            }
            if($_SESSION['identifiant'] == 1){
                echo "<script>location.href='http://127.0.0.1/formacao/principalUSU.php';</script>";
                    exit();
            }
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

**A página de validação:**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['id']) OR empty($_POST['senha']) AND (`ativo` = 1)) {
  header("Location: principal.php");
   exit;
} else {
    if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['id']) OR empty($_POST['senha']) AND (`ativo` = 0){
        header("Location: principalUSU.php");
         exit;
}

// Tenta se conectar ao servidor MySQL
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
// Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
$identifiant = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['identifiant']);
$senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);
$ativo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ativo']);

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `identifiant`, `senha`, `ativo`  FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`identifiant` = '". $identifiant ."') AND (`senha` = '". $senha ."') AND (`ativo` = '". $ativo ."')";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
  // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
  echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
} else {
  // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
  $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}
?>
```

Essa página ainda não está sendo redirecionada para validação porque o action está vazio e o action está vazio porque a página de validação não funciona.

Todo usuário cadastrado na tabela consegue entrar se seu identifiant e senha estiverem certo, mas a parte de permissão, que redireciona o admin pra uma página e o usuário para outra, não.

Eu não sei bem como posso fazer isso, por isso, aceito ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim ficou a página de validação:

```
<?php
//Esse login ficou meio complicadinho, então vou deixar comentado: 
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Primeiro verifica se o post não está vazio
if (!empty($_POST) AND !empty($_POST['identifiant']) OR !empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('db_formacao');
    // Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
    $identifiant = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['identifiant']);
    $senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);
    $ativo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ativo']);

    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `identifiant`, `senha`, `ativo`  FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`identifiant` = '". $identifiant ."') AND (`senha` = '". $senha ."')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
      // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
      echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
    } else {
      $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
      // Verifica se o usuário é 0 ou 1

      if ($resultado['ativo'] == 0) { header("Location: principalUSU.php"); } 
      else { header("Location: principal.php"); }

      exit;
    }
}
?>
```

O formulário de login:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="
    align-content: center;
    margin-left: 160px;">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="
    margin-top: 14px;">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Login</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="background: rgba(32, 40, 76, 0.59);">
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($erro)) 
                            if(count($erro) > 0){ ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <?php foreach($erro as $msg) echo "$msg <br>"; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php 
                            }
                            ?>
                        <form method="post" action="validacao.php" role="form">
                            <fieldset style="background: #9498a9;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" name="identifiant">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" required placeholder="Senha" name="senha" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Lembrar-me
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" name="login" value="true" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="background: #232b4f; border-color: #e2e2e2;">Login</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não entendi muito bem onde entra a referência do código na página de validação. Acredito que esteja dentro de conexão. Se for, você não precisa usar a validação nessa página, apenas a conexão. Tente o seguinte:

```
   <?php
  session_start();

        //Login de Usários
if($_POST){

  include('class/conexao.php');

  $erro = array();

  // Captação de dados
  $senha = mysqli->escape_string($_POST[senha]);
  $_SESSION['identifiant'] = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['identifiant']);

  // Validação de dados
  if(strlen($identifiant) < 7 || strlen($identifiant) > 7){
      $erro[] = "Preencha sua <strong>identifiant</strong> corretamente.";
}else if(strlen($senha) < 5 || strlen($senha) > 16){
      $erro[] = "Preencha sua <strong>senha</strong> corretamente.";
}else{
  //Até aqui, se não tiver nenhum erro nessa lista de erros aí, prossegue.

      $sql = "SELECT senha as senha, identifiant as valor
      FROM usuarios
      WHERE identifiant = '$_SESSION[identifiant]'";
      $que = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
      $dado = $que->fetch_assoc();

      if($que->num_rows == 0){
          $erro[] = "Usuário ou senha inválidos.";

      }else{

                  if($_SESSION['identifiant'] == 0){
                                  echo "<script>location.href='http://127.0.0.1/formacao/principal.php';</script>";
                                  exit();
                  }
                  if($_SESSION['identifiant'] == 1){
                                  echo "<script>location.href='http://127.0.0.1/formacao/principalUSU.php';</script>";
                                  exit();
                  }



  }

}
}
    ?>


     <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="
        margin-top: 14px;">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Login</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" style="background: rgba(32, 40, 76, 0.59);">
                            <?php 
                            if(isset($erro)) 
                                if(count($erro) > 0){ ?>
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <?php foreach($erro as $msg) echo "$msg <br>"; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php 
                                }
                                ?>
                            <form method="post" action="" role="form">
                                <fieldset style="background: #9498a9;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" name="identifiant">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" required placeholder="Senha" name="senha" type="password" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Lembrar-me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" name="login" value="true" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="background: #232b4f; border-color: #e2e2e2;">Login</button>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Então, copiei o seu código só que onde está ID eu coloquei identifiant e onde está identifiant eu coloquei ativo porque o nome da coluna que está armazenada o 0 ou 1 é esse.

Comment: Mudei todos os mysql para mysqli como recomendado, aliás, obrigada por isso. Mas a página de validação ainda não funciona, dá aquele erro 500. :/

Comment: Alterei o código... veja se consegue agora.

Comment: Oi Mariana. Fiz um novo ajuste. Veja se consegue agora.

Comment: Então, eu tentei usar seu código, mas a página parou de funcionar. Vou ver se não é algum erro meu de identação ou coisa assim.

Comment: Vou editar minha pergunta pra você ver como ficou